# How to inject handlebar js template using content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, handlebars.js, template-engine

I need to inject a div in the current tab on it right side as a slidebar. So am using content_script in manifest to load the inject scripts. But here I need more html elements to inject so createElement in js will make my content.js ugly. So I need some js template engine to write html and inject those to the dom using content.js. I prefer handlebar js, since it supports csp using its per-compiler.

Am using background.js to send a message from there to content.js to inject the dom. That part is fine. Now only the content.js has to include the html template to inject the plenty of my requirment inside the page.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name":"Stack me",
    "version":"0.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "description":"hack the dom, inject our dom as a slidbar",
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background/background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
                  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["thirdParty/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "thirdParty/handlebars-v4.1.1.js", "content/content.js"]
        }
    ],
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon.png"
    },

    "icons":{
        "16":"icons/icon.png",
        "128":"icons/icon.png"
    },
      "web_accessible_resources": [
            "icons/icon.png"
      ]
}
```

background.js

```
console.log("background js")

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(iconClicked)

function iconClicked(tab) {
  let msg = { type: "clientAuth"}
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg)
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch(message.type){
    case "clientAuth":
     registerIfNeeded();
    break;
  }
}

function registerIfNeeded() {
  //call api
  //UI
  if(document.getElementById("myDivId"))
    document.getElementById("myDivId").remove()
  else {
    ...
    var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    div.id = 'myDivId';
        ...
  }
}

//How to replace the below code to work with templates, which can be included here.
/*<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>AJ</h1>
    <div class="body">
      aj
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);*/
```

Comment: Your content script seems to have  `<script>` right inside the JS code which is an invalid syntax. Instead you can store it inside a backtick string (template string literal).

Comment: @wOxxOm I accept the syntax error. Can we use the handlebar compile like this inside the. Will that works?
`var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);`

Comment: "I accept the syntax error" - even if you accept it, the browser won't accept it so it won't work. Like I said, store it inside a string `var source = `<div class=......`

Comment: @wOxxOm Come on!! Its not the syntax error am speaking in the question. Its all about a hint to tweak my code to use a html template. For you, I can edit my code posted there!!

Comment: Still vague to me. Without a real reproducible [MCVE](/help/mcve) I doubt anyone could help, but maybe I'm wrong and someone could make sense of this setup.

Comment: @wOxxOm To be more specific, which is the best approach to add plenty of html elements in div#`myDivId`

Comment: I've already suggested using a literal backtick string in your content script. Not sure why that was ignored.

Comment: @wOxxOm you are telling something like `let source = '<div>more..</div>'; div.innerHTML = source;` But for many dom elemnet with specific style, can we go like this?

Comment: What's wrong with "many dom elemnet with specific style"? I don't understand the question.